# Как записать значения из JS в отдельные переменные?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть такой код:

```
ro_prices = {};
ro_prices[2231] = {};
ro_prices[2231]['price'] = 18910.0000;
ro_prices[2231]['discounts'] = [];
ro_prices[2231]['specials'] = [];
ro_prices[2232] = {};
ro_prices[2232]['price'] = 21000.0000;
ro_prices[2232]['discounts'] = [];
ro_prices[2232]['specials'] = [];
ro_prices[2233] = {};
ro_prices[2233]['price'] = 35880.0000;
ro_prices[2233]['discounts'] = [];
ro_prices[2233]['specials'] = [];
ro_prices[2234] = {};
ro_prices[2234]['price'] = 38360.0000;
ro_prices[2234]['discounts'] = [];
ro_prices[2234]['specials'] = [];
ro_prices[2235] = {};
ro_prices[2235]['price'] = 22560.0000;
ro_prices[2235]['discounts'] = [];
ro_prices[2235]['specials'] = [];
ro_prices[2236] = {};
```

и

```
for (var prop in ro_prices) {
  var price = eval("ro_prices[" + prop + "]" + "['price']"); 
  console.log(price);
}
```

Выдаёт мне:

```
18910.0000
21000.0000
35880.0000
38360.0000
22560.0000
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить только 21000.0000 или только 38360.0000 (только второе или только 4ое значение)?

Comment: Интересно, к чему там eval) `var price = ro_prices[prop].price;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

запишите результат в массив и обращайтесь к массиву по индексу

```
arr = []

for (var prop in ro_prices) {
  var price = eval("ro_prices[" + prop + "]" + "['price']"); 
  arr.push(price);
}

console.log(arr[2], arr[4]);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Object.values(ro_prices)[2].price)
console.log(Object.values(ro_prices)[4].price)
```